# Multiple logical operator || (OR) conditions in for loop in C

Tags: c, loops, logical-operators

I started studying C a week ago and decided to write my own [tic-tac-toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) game for practise.

I have a game loop in **main**:

```
for(int i = 1; player1.isWinner!=1 || player2.isWinner!=1 || noWinner!=1; i++){...}
```

Where **i** - counts turns and condition of end of the game is one of players has won, or no one has won (draw).

For now, it quits executing only if **all** conditions are 1.

How can I make it work right?

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||`? Also, you could use `_Bool` and get rid of the `!=1`, which makes the condition a bit easier to follow.

Comment: I think the core of the problem here is misunderstanding boolean algebra, namely [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). Which are easy to understand if you skip past all the mathematician secret handshake bs. "Apples are not blue and they are not purple" is the same thing as saying "Apples are not blue or purple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is a value of 1 where someone won?

If so, then you would need check any of those conditions is true and loop if they are not:

```
!(player1.isWinner==1 || player2.isWinner==1 || noWinner==1)
```

Or using AND, check and loop when none are set:

```
(player1.isWinner!=1 && player2.isWinner!=1 && noWinner!=1)
```

Comment: @ГригорийШепелев Note that using boolean logic, you can also write (provided you only use 0 or 1-- false or true)  `if(condition1 || condition2)` instead of `if(condition1==1 || condition2==1)`. I usually find it much more readable. Other than that, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Consider extracting the condition to a well-named function in order to aid readability and maintanability:

```
int hasWinner(/*...*/) 
{  
    return player1.isWinner == 1 || player2.isWinner == 1 || noWinner == 1;
}
```

It then becomes obvious what the condition should be:

```
for(int i = 1; !hasWinner(/*...*/); i++){ /*...*/ }
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using some sort of backwards boolean logic. If 1 represents the boolean value `true`, then the condition should be

```
!(player1.isWinner || player2.isWinner || noWinner)
```

This assumes that you set `player1.isWinner` to 1 when player1 has won.

It would probably be easier to use `bool` with values `true` or `false` from stdbool.h.